# Google Tag Manager: Multiple Countries under the same domain

Tags: google-tag-manager

I work for an ecommerce country that will have a web presence in multiple countries. Currently we are using Google Tag Manaager for the US. What is the best approach for adding countries to Google tag manager? Is it as simple as setting up a container for each country?

The URLs will resemble

- http://www.example.com/US
- http://www.example.com/IT
- http://www.example.com/GB

Thanks,

Wade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even use one container for all countries and different triggers (rules) based on URLs to fire tags.

Comment: Thanks.

Where can I read more about these specific use cases?

Comment: Best place to start is https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2644396?hl=en. Here you can read about URL based rules